# I am trying to finish this code for this menu and cant figure out why it won't loop correctly?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have this code that I am doing and cant for the life of me figure out why it isn't looping correctly and adding the amount of the products together it seems like it only reads the first statement in the while loop and thats all the data it pulls from. I need it to also not to keep looping back to the first while statement but to continue on with the same phrase "Please enter another item from the menu above: " any help is appreciated, Thanks guys.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {        //Declare Variables

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nProduct = 0;           //Stores the value entered by the user
    int nPrice = 0;             //Stores sum of values entered
    int nCount = 0;
    int nSum = 0;
    double dTax = 0.0;
    double dTotal = 0.0;

    final int SENTINEL = 10; //Used to end loop
    final double TAX = .065;


    System.out.print("Please enter the your name: ");
        String sName = input.nextLine( );

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("BEST PURCHASE PRODUCTS: ");
    System.out.println("1. Smartphone          $249");
    System.out.println("2. Smartphone Case     $39");
    System.out.println("3. PC Laptop           $1149");
    System.out.println("4. Tablet              $349");
    System.out.println("5. Tablet Case         $49");
    System.out.println("6. eReader             $119");
    System.out.println("7. PC Desktop          $889");
    System.out.println("8. LED Monitor         $299");
    System.out.println("9. Laser Printer       $399");
    System.out.println("10.Complete my order");

    while (nProduct != SENTINEL) {
        nSum = nPrice + nSum;
        nCount++; 
        System.out.print("Please enter item from the menu above: ");
        nProduct = input.nextInt();

        if (nProduct == 1) {
            nPrice += 249;
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }

        else if (nProduct == 2) {
            nPrice += 39;
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }

        else if (nProduct == 3 ) {
            nPrice += 1149; 
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }

        else if (nProduct == 4 ) {
              nPrice += 349;
              System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }

        else if (nProduct == 5 ) {
            nPrice += 49;
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }

        else if (nProduct == 6 ) {
            nPrice += 119;
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }

        else if (nProduct == 7 ) {
            nPrice += 899;
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }

        else if (nProduct == 8 ) {
            nPrice += 299;
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        } 

        else if(nProduct == 9 ) {
            nPrice += 399;
            System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
            nProduct = input.nextInt();
        }
    }    

    dTax = (nPrice * TAX);
    dTotal = dTax + nPrice;

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Best   Purchase,"+sName);
    System.out.println("Total Items Ordered: " + nCount);
    System.out.println("Price of items ordered: $" + nSum);
    System.out.println("Sales Tax: $" + dTax);
    System.out.println("Total amount due: $" + dTotal);
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Frank...but it looks like nSum is not going to come out correctly here.

Instead of...

```
nPrice += xxx;
```

in each statement...you should simply put

```
nSum += xxx;
```

and stop evaluating sum again at the top. As you have it now, you are constantly increasing the value of nPrice. Another option is to simply set nPrice in each if statement, and evaluate nSum at the top or bottom of the loop.

```
nPrice = xxx;
```

You are also getting an extra count because you are processing nCount++ BEFORE you actually read the item. Meaning if you type in "10" to quit, you already added an item.

You could try something like this. It's messy and took my 5 minutes, and is probably not the best way but it should work:

```
System.out.print("Please enter item from the menu above: ");
nProduct = input.nextInt()

while (nProduct != SENTINEL) {
    nProduct = input.nextInt()

    if (nProduct == 1) {
        nSum += 249;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 2) {
        nSum += 39;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 3 ) {
        nSum += 1149;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 4 ) {
        nSum += 349;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 5 ) {
        nSum += 49;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 6 ) {
        nSum += 119;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 7 ) {
        nSum += 899;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 8 ) {
        nSum += 299;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    } 
    else if(nProduct == 9 ) {
        nSum += 399;
        System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");
        nCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this helped, all the calculations are correct now except for nCount after I terminate the loop by typing in 10 it adds another line and counting it one last time before actually ending

Comment: Please enter item from the menu above: 1
Please enter another item from the menu above:  2
Please enter another item from the menu above:  10
Please enter another item from the menu above: /*this line here it adds after termination*\  
Thank you for ordering with Best Purchase, nick
Total Items Ordered: 3 */and counts it here*\

Comment: Edited. Frank got you mostly there, though. His solution is a lot more elegant.

Comment: Perfect Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The additional `input.nextInt()` in each `if` block makes no sense here. This way you have to enter two numbers in each iteration. The following loop should do what you want:

```
System.out.print("Please enter item from the menu above: ");
while ((nProduct = input.nextInt()) != SENTINEL) {
    nSum = nPrice + nSum;
    nCount++;
    System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above:  ");

    if (nProduct == 1) {
        nPrice += 249;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 2) {
        nPrice += 39;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 3 ) {
        nPrice += 1149; 
    }
    else if (nProduct == 4 ) {
          nPrice += 349;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 5 ) {
        nPrice += 49;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 6 ) {
        nPrice += 119;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 7 ) {
        nPrice += 899;
    }
    else if (nProduct == 8 ) {
        nPrice += 299;
    } 
    else if(nProduct == 9 ) {
        nPrice += 399;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what you want to accomplish with the statement `nSum = nPrice + nSum;`. This calculates the sum of all partial sums.

Comment: A Do-While loop may also be considered since it is pointless to evaluate the terms of the while loop prior to processing the loop.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you, except now its adding an extra line after I end the loop by typing in 10 and nCount is counting it

Comment: @NicholasNPeck: Right, have edited my answer and moved the input directly into the loop condition. Might be a bit harder to read but will not print the extra output.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the prompt for & reading of input *after* the whole if/else business, so that (a) you would only have to write it once and (b) it would get done even if `nProduct` did not match a product.  But you would need to move the *first* prompt & read to just before the loop starts.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @scott-hunter's solution, but an alternate method to change the prompt so that you have something like this:

```
String prompt = "Please enter item from the menu above: ";
while (nProduct != SENTINEL) {
    // Some code ...
    System.out.println(prompt);
    // ... more code
    prompt = "Please enter another item from the menu above: ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take out

```
System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
nProduct = input.nextInt();
```

from every if statement, this should fix your problem.

Basically, you are doing this:

1. Ask for a number.
2. Check the number, ask for a number.
3. Ask for a number.

If you remove the above code from each if statement, you will be doing

1. Ask for a number.
2. Check the number.
3. Ask for a number.
4. Check the number.

Which is how you want it.